# Removing PPA causing GPG error

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, sudo, ppa

When I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1436387333
```

How can I locate and remove the PPA which is causing this error?

Comment: `grep -r 'download.opensuse.org' /etc/apt`

Comment: how to remove the ppa after locating it?

Comment: What is the output of the command above? Run this command in your terminal.

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./ 
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
` `@A.B.`

Comment: `sudo sed -i '/download.opensuse.org/d' /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thank you. Please post an answer to this question so that others can also get help from your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command

```
grep -r 'download.opensuse.org' /etc/apt
```

shows where the repository is configured, e.g.:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./ 
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:# deb-src http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./ 
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./ 
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./
```

In your case it is in

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

With this knowledge you can remove the entry with the help of `sed`

```
sudo sed -i '/download.opensuse.org/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and to avoid confusion in the future you also should remove the entry in your backup file

```
sudo sed -i '/download.opensuse.org/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.save
```

Now update the package information

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and the problem is gone.